# How to scale Hibernate Readers?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch

I am trying to scale up a rather simple Springbatch tasklet.
Here is the situation:

- HibernatePagingItemReader
- Custom processor: perform a webservice query based on data from HibernatePagingItemReader
- Custom writer

The bottleneck is my processor, because webservice query is slow, and it can be easly parrellelized.

I added a task-executor (org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) on my tasklet, but it does not scale linearly: Above 5 threads, the total execution time is the same.

Spring docs says that readers are not off-the-shelf scalable, but my needs are much simpler.
Every record fetched by the reader is indepedant, so I could execute readers in parrallel.

My Questions are:

- How readers are executed in a multi-threaded context? Are they parrallelized, or do they distribut data to parrallelized readers?
- If readers are parrallelized, I would think that I should have smaller amount of records (setting maxItemCount) to distribute these records to processors

Any other ideas to scale up that?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, any kind of batch library defines an upper limit to your thread pool that is used to do parallel work.
From your description, it sounds like you hit the upper limit. Try increasing it.

Comment: thanks for the comments, but that's my problem: increasing the number of threads does not decrease the total time of execution (starting from 5 threads). I feel that the bottleneck is the reader. I am trying to figure out how to do that.